# Sending data with CURL GET

Tags: http, curl, elasticsearch

I thought GET is not supposed to have a body. But in the context of elasticsearch, I keep seeing this kind of query ([see here for instance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)):

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_msearch --data-binary @requests; echo
```

How is the binary data sent in this case? Can somebody explains what is going on and how this works?
I first thought it was converted to a POST but, I put a proxy in front of  Elasticsearch and saw that curl was really sending a GET. Though I could find the data neither in the header, nor in the parameter, nor in the body. So it seems like my proxy also got confused by this request.

But when I execute the request directly against elasticsearch, it works just fine. What gives?

Answer (score 3):

`GET`s with bodies are allowed but not considered to be very "meaningful". You can see this question and answer for a full discussion. [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

and this answer about your proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/978173/3516034